# disable render of all collections with python in blender 2.8

Tags: collections

I am trying to disable all collections in the render with python in Blender 2.8

It works on top-level collections with the code below, but ignores nested collections.

```py
import bpy
coll = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
for x in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection.children:
        x.hide_render = True
```

Is there a way to get all collections, regardless of hierarchy?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se. Thank you for your question, be aware, that the 2.8 api is still under development, although I'd think, that collection access won't change anytime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to Blender's internal data is achieved through [`bpy.data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.data.html). This is usually also easier to maintain, since context access (`bpy.context`) is context-dependent.

Access all collections through:

```
bpy.data.collections
```

Render-restricting all collections:

```
import bpy

coll = bpy.data.collections

for c in coll:
    c.hide_render=True
```

Comment: Ah! That was easy. Thanks Leander. 
This works:
`import bpy
coll = bpy.data.collections
for c in coll:
    c.hide_render=True`

Comment: Forgot to include the final code, added your example, glad it worked. For future reference, if any answer is missing a piece of information (like your code example) feel free to suggest an edit yourself. Comments are only temporary and may get removed.

Answer (score 5):

**With recursion**

As well as setting attributes on all collections in `bpy.data.collections` can recursively walk the children.

This will only set the property on descendants of the collection. In this case `bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection`

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

coll = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection

for c in traverse_tree(coll):
    c.hide_render = True
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying actually to activate an excluded collection so I've tried to set `c.hide_render=False` but it reports back an error that `AttributeError: 'LayerCollection' object has no attribute 'hide_render'`. Then I've tried also `bpy.context.layer_collection.children[c.name].exclude = False` `layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[c.name]` `bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layer_collection`  but then I've got `KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "<collection_name>" not found'` any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please note difference between `context.view_layer.layer_collection` and `context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection`

Comment: Yup, you are right I overlooked the last `.collection` but still `c.hide_render = False` doesn't seem to activate my collection.

Comment: Look for set active collection.

Comment: Got it to work ;-)