# Blender Python: Exclude Collections from View Layers

Tags: python, collections, viewlayers

I would like to replicate in a script what happens if i exclude a collection from a view layer via hotkey E (bpy.ops.outliner.collection_exclude_set()).

I cannot seem to find that exclude in the tree. Is the E hotkey doing a hide render and viewport, or is there more to that? How should i best approach this?

Thanks, Axel

Comment: Hi Robert, unfortunately not really - i can get it done with the active_layer_collection, but what i want to achive is the following: Lets say i got 3 view layers (A,B,C) and 3 collections (a,b,c). I need collection a to be the only active one in view layer A, and so on. So i have to do things outside the currently active layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO is a dupe easier to explain with answer... see RG has beaten me to it.. anyhoo

> - i can get it done with the active_layer_collection, but what i want to achive is the following: Lets say i got 3 view layers (A,B,C) and 3
>     collections (a,b,c). I need collection a to be the only active one in
>     view layer A, and so on. So i have to do things outside the currently
>     active layer

```
>>> for vl in C.scene.view_layers:
...     for l in vl.layer_collection.children:
...         l.exclude = l.name.lower() != vl.name.lower()
...
```

Comment: I didn't get the path right. `C.scene.view_layers[x].layer_collection.children[y].exclude` was what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This only works great, yet only for non-nested collections - which rough direction would i go if the layers are nested? Thanks!

Comment: Think the answers are basically the same.  Would need to recurse the collections see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137866/15543

Answer (score 3):

First you need to retrieve the view layer you'd like to modify. The view layers in the scene can be accessed through `bpy.context.scene.view_layers` or if you want to access view layers of other scenes you can use `bpy.data.scenes["Name of the scene"].view_layers`.

In order to exclude a specific collection the [`LayerCollection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html#bpy.types.LayerCollection.exclude) has to be accessed, because that is where the `exclude` property is stored. While iterating over the children of the master layer collection from the view layer, we can check for each entry if it matches the collection that we want to include. If it doesn't, it can be excluded through its `LayerCollection` and otherwise be included.

```
import bpy

def include_only_one_collection(view_layer: bpy.types.ViewLayer, collection_include: bpy.types.Collection):
    for layer_collection in view_layer.layer_collection.children:
        if layer_collection.collection != collection_include:
            layer_collection.exclude = True
        else:
            layer_collection.exclude = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    view_layer = bpy.context.scene.view_layers["View Layer"]
    collection_include = bpy.data.collections["Collection"]
    include_only_one_collection(view_layer, collection_include)
```

Comment: Thank you, Robert!

Comment: And if you need to exclude a few more collections? I'm writing a script to have several enabled and disabled groups in each scene. but for some reason it does not turn off more than one

Comment: @Welet You would have to set the `exclude` property for each collection accordingly. Perhaps it would be a good idea to post a new question to explain the particular problem you're facing if this answer does not solve it.