# Disable collection on all layers except one?

Tags: interface, workflow, collections, outliner

I have 10 layers and every time I make a new collection I have to click on each layer to exclude collection from every layer. For example, I created collection on layer 1 and need it to be enabled only on layer 1. Is there an option or hotkey to *exclude collection from all layers except this one*?

[image]

Comment: You can just click and drag down/up and it will select/deselect multiple at a time.

Comment: I need smth like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160759/60139 but i don't understand anything in coding and when copy-paste the code it does nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following Add-on code can do this for you. Save the code as `oco.py` and install that file as an Add-on in Blender. You can then activate it when searching for `Collection Ops` in the Add-ons section of Blender.

Once done, right-click in the Outliner on the collection you would like to exclude for all other View Layers and select the command on the bottom:

[image: Menu entry]

Here's the Add-on code:

```
'''
Created on 09.07.2019

@author: r.trummer
'''
bl_info = {
    "name": "Collection Ops",
    "author": "Rainer Trummer",
    "version": (0, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "description": "provides functions in the Outliner context menu to work with collections",
    "category": "Object"
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty


#===============================================================================
#    Operators
#===============================================================================
def get_flattened_layer_collections(layer_collection):
    for c in layer_collection.children:
        yield c
        yield from get_flattened_layer_collections(c)


def find_layer_collection(view_layer, layer_collection, **kwargs):
    pool = kwargs.setdefault('pool', view_layer.layer_collection)

    colls = get_flattened_layer_collections(pool)

    for c in colls:
        if c.collection == layer_collection.collection:
            return c


class COLLECTION_OT_Unset_For_Other_View_Layers(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "collection.unset_for_other_view_layers"
    bl_label = "Exclude In Other View Layers"
    bl_description = 'excludes collection in all other view layers'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    deactivate: BoolProperty(default = True)

    def execute(self, context):
        for vl in context.scene.view_layers:
            if vl != context.view_layer:
                vl_collection = find_layer_collection(vl, context.view_layer.active_layer_collection)
                vl_collection.exclude = True

        context.view_layer.depsgraph.update()

        return {'FINISHED'}


#===============================================================================
#    put the commands into menus
#===============================================================================
def draw_outliner_collection_commands(self, context:bpy.context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator(COLLECTION_OT_Unset_For_Other_View_Layers.bl_idname)


#===============================================================================
#    registration code
#===============================================================================
__classes__ = (
    COLLECTION_OT_Unset_For_Other_View_Layers,
)


def register():
    for cl in __classes__:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cl)

    bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_collection.append(draw_outliner_collection_commands)


def unregister():
    for cl in reversed(__classes__):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cl)

    bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_collection.remove(draw_outliner_collection_commands)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```