# Create a Collection inside another Collection with python

Tags: python, scripting, collections

How to create a Collection inside another existing Collection with Python?
[image]

Comment: `bpy.context.scene.collection.children['Collection'].children.link(bpy.data.collections.new('Sub Collection'))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each collection has a [`children` *(collection)* property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html?#bpy.types.Collection.children). Easy to figure out using the python console:

```
>>> C.scene.collection.
                       all_objects
                       animation_data_clear(
                       animation_data_create(
                       as_pointer(
                       bl_rna
                       bl_rna_get_subclass(
                       bl_rna_get_subclass_py(
                       children
                       ...
```

To get the first level of all sub-collections, you can just iterate through the list:

```
>>> for coll in C.scene.collection.children:
...     print (coll.name)
...     
Collection
Collection 2
Collection 3
...
```

To add a new collection, create a new data-block and then use [`.link(collection)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionChildren.html#bpy.types.CollectionChildren.link) method to add it to whatever your *main* collection is:

```
>>> C.scene.collection.children.link(
link()
CollectionChildren.link(child)
Add this collection as child of this collection

>>> my_sub_coll = bpy.data.collections.new("My Sub Collection")
>>> C.scene.collection.children.link(my_sub_coll)
```

The same principle applies to all collections, no matter the collection is on the first or any other level. Example on how to add a new *(sub) collection* to the *active* collection:

```
>>> active_coll = C.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection
>>> active_coll.children.link(my_sub_coll)
```

---

You can also specify the each collection by its name `C.scene.collection.children["Collection"]` or you can even use the index operator `C.scene.collection.children[0]` but that's error prone. In case the name of the collection or the scene hierarchy changes you're lost. Better practice is using pythons `get()` method to basically perform a search for the collection in the first place:

```
>>> C.scene.collection.children.get("Collection")
bpy.data.collections['Collection']
```

*Basic* example using `.get()`:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

main_coll = C.scene.collection.children.get("Collection")
if main_coll:
    # Create the new collection
    my_sub_coll = bpy.data.collections.new("My Sub Collection")
    # Add it to the found collection
    main_coll.children.link(my_sub_coll)
```

*Advanced* example on how to add a new collection to an arbitrary collection in the scene using a recursive loop based on https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137866:

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

coll = bpy.context.scene.collection

for c in traverse_tree(coll):
    if c.name == "MyCollection": # Specify the name of you main collection here
        my_sub_coll = bpy.data.collections.new("My Sub Collection")
        # Add it to the main collection
        c.children.link(my_sub_coll)
```

---

Notice that you add *objects* to the collection(s) the same way by just passing an object  when calling the [`.link(object)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionObjects.html#bpy.types.CollectionObjects.link) method on the actual object *(collection)* property, which is actually pretty nice and convenient:

```
>>> my_sub_coll.objects.link(C.object)
```

Comment: Simply `coll.name` in console will print.

Comment: Do you think this makes it easier to read for beginners? @batFINGER

Comment: Possibly not.  IMO It is easier to sniff around  in  console without typing in  print and its braces. Prob realize:  I'm a fan of answers explaining via use of console

Comment: This adds the subcollection as a child of the Scene Collection and not of the default Collection, as in OP’s screenshot. Should read `C.scene.collection.children['Collection'].children.link(my_sub_coll)`.

Comment: The OP should be able to apply the principle to whatever collection based on this answer *"then use .link(collection) method to add it to whatever your main collection is"*. Specifying the name is bad practice IMO, I added an example using `get()` for completeness @Pisurquatre

Comment: @brockmann Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

posting how I do this in blender 2.90 for others in case it's useful.

doing it like this doesn't require context or ui polling.

```
import bpy

#create scene collection
shared_assets_collection_name = "Shared Assets"
shared_assets_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(shared_assets_collection_name)
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(shared_assets_collection)  

#create subcollection
cname = "Actors"
c = bpy.data.collections.new(cname)
bpy.data.collections.get(shared_assets_collection_name).children.link(c)
```

Comment: How this is different to my answer? ... Apparently nothing changed. Also you're linking a new collection to the scene collection **in *context** -> *"this doesn't require context or ui polling."* not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: yeah you're right they are both similiar.   I couldn't find a 3 line solution that compiled so I thought I'd post one.  
although a two line version might have been better.


```my_collection = bpy.data.collections.new("My Collection Name Here")
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(my_collection)```

Comment: For a minimal example see *Basic example using .get()* in my answer. Consider that your version of it: `bpy.data.collections.get(shared_assets_collection_name).children.link(c)` can error.