# Duplicate a mesh via python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I'd like to improve my duplicator script.
bpy.ops.object.duplicate() seems to require me to select the object first.
I'd like to just feed the object straight to it instead.

Is there a smarter way to handle it than I did so far?

```
def duplicator(name):
    # select the object
    obj = bpy.data.objects.get(name)
    obj.select_set(True)

    # Loop 3 times, duplicate it, name it
    for i in range(1,4):
        # duplicate selected object
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate()

        # name new object with a string and number
        newObj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        newName = 'Plane_' + str ( i )
        newObj.name = newName


duplicator('Plane_0')
```

Comment: `new_obj = obj.copy()`

Answer (score 4):

**Another take**

Before closing as dupe, thought I would put together another take on this for example sake.

Added a method that simply yields n copies of the given object with a new name and suffix.  If linked is `False` the object copies all share the same mesh.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context 

def object_duper(ob, name, n=1, linked=False):
    assert(ob)
    for i in range(n):
        copy = ob.copy()
        if ob.data and linked:
            copy.data = copy.data.copy()
        copy.name = f"{name}_{i + 1}"
        yield copy

# testing

ob = context.object

for o in object_duper(ob, ob.name, 5):
    context.scene.collection.objects.link(o)
```

This method simply dupes the objects which will naturally be added to `bpy.data.objects` collection. I have not put in the link to collection.  Could emulate your answer method with, and pass the collection

```
def dupe_n_link(collection, ob, name, n=1, linked=False):
    for o in object_duper(ob, name, n=n, linked=linked):
        collection.objects.link(o)
```

Can think of many reasons to create multiple duplicates, may not always wish  to add all dupes to same collection, may wish to add one to each collection

```
ob = context.object

colls = bpy.data.collections

for c, o in zip(colls, object_duper(ob, "Basis", n=len(colls))):
    c.objects.link(o)
```

Comment: is it possible to unlink the material as well as you do with the mesh in the duplicate object by using the `linked=True` flag. I want my material in the duplicate object to have the same properties as the material in the original object but at the same time once the duplicate object is created any changes in one of the two materials later on not to affect the other one.

Comment: Ok I think I found the solution `copy.active_material = copy.active_material.copy()` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @batFINGER and brockmann.

To duplicate an object and add it to a collection, you could use the following code

````
import bpy

def duplicator(
        ob_name, new_ob_name, 
        col_name, amount):

    new_obs = []

    for i in range(1, amount):

        # get the object
        ob = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(ob_name)

        # copy, name and store new_name
        new_ob = ob.copy()
        new_name = new_ob_name + str ( i )
        new_ob.name = new_name
        new_obs.append(new_name)

        # place it in the collection
        col = bpy.context.scene.collection.children.get(col_name)
        #bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(newCol) <-- in case you need to add the collection to the scene
        col.objects.link(new_ob)
        print ( col.name ) 

    return new_obs

duplicator('Cube', 'Cube_', 'coverage', 5)

```
````

Comment: Depending on what you do, there is still a lot which can be optimized like getting the object as well as the collection per scene `C.scene.objects.get(ob_name)` instead of the data block, python comes with `enumerate()` and I would not recommend to hard code the collection name: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167440/31447

Comment: Hi brockmann,

wow, thank you, this is nice. I've updated the script a bit to reflect the changes.
Any reason why you prefer using C.scene.objects instead of bpy.data.objects ?

Comment: That's close but won't work unfortunately. `C` is a convenience variable in the console to get the `context` so either create the variable before `C = bpy.context` or use `bpy.context.scene.objects.get(ob_name)`. Why? It's safer, you can *limit the scope* to the *scene in context* rather than iterating through all objects in the entire *blend* file. Also consider renaming your arguments to something like `ob_name`, `new_ob_name`, `coll_name` and `amount` -> according to pep: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I was struggling a bit with the names, but your suggestion & pep-0008 are quite helpful. Updated code once again. Cheers dude!

Comment: ... and the collection using `get()` as well like: `col = C.scene.collection.children.get("Collection")`. Once you have it, use it to link the objects `col.objects.link(new_obj)`...